# Qu'est-ce qu'une autorité « chef de file » ?

Tags: adjectifs, terminologie, informatique, droit-et-justice, guillemets

> En même temps que sa plainte contre Google, la Quadrature du Net a
>   déposé des plaintes de même type contre deux autres géants du net,
>   Facebook et Amazon. Elles ne seront pas instruites directement par la
>   Commission française, mais par ses équivalents irlandais pour Facebook
>   et luxembourgeois pour Amazon, qui sont les **autorités « chef de file »**
>   pour l'UE pour ces deux entreprises.
>
> [ [*Données personnelles: l'UE impose une amende de 50 millions
>   d'euros à Google*](https://www.lapresse.ca/techno/mobilite/201901/21/01-5211779-donnees-personnelles-lue-impose-une-amende-de-50-millions-deuros-a-google.php), La Presse ]

Dans le secteur privé, j'ai l'habitude de retrouver la locution nominale comme équivalent de *market leader* en langue anglaise soit la « personne physique ou morale qui devance la concurrence par l'excellence de ses activités, et qui exerce une influence dans son domaine » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869731)). Mais il s'agit ici d'un locution adjectivale dans le secteur public...

---

- Est-ce une transposition du sens au secteur public ; est-ce
  tributaire d'une particularité de l'Irlande et du Luxembourg dans un
  domaine ; pourquoi les guillemets ; incidemment quel serait un synonyme usuel ?

Comment: Le « le » démonstratif n'existe pas en français (français canadien ?). J'aurais mis une virgule après « équivalents ».

Comment: @LPH Je ne comprends pas, c'est « comme équivalent de market leader », comment peut-il y avoir une virgule ? De quel « le » parlez-vous ? Merci !

Comment: par ses équivalents irlandais pour …; de l'Irlande et du Luxembourg dans **le** domaine…

Comment: @LPH La formulation m'apparaît parfaitement régulière et naturelle, c'est à vous à étayer l'affirmation qu'elle n'existe pas, pas à moi de prouver qu'elle existe. Vous pouvez en faire une question en bonne et due forme pour voir ce qu'on en pense. Ça m'apparaît simplement comme l'ellipse de la spécification du domaine . Merci !

Comment: Un « à » est préférable pour l'adjectif suivi d'un verbe :  habitué à retrouver (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habitu%C3%A9+%C3%A0+retrouver%2Chabitu%C3%A9+de+retrouver&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabitu%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20retrouver%3B%2Cc0) ; « de » s'emploie avec l'emploi substantif suivi d'un substantif (habitué de repas copieux, habitué de lectures assidues, habitué de musique swing,…)

Comment: @LPH C'est _rare et archaïque_ en effet (LBU14 § 904, 907) : _La France n'était pas habituée de courir si souvent à Reims._ (Druon) ; _Loin des lieux où le temps l'habitua de vivre._ (Chénier). L'[_affirmation_](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/habituer.htm) de la capsule de l'UdeM à l'effet qu'il s'agit là d'une _erreur_ manque de nuance, puisqu'on a l'emploi classique _au moins occasionnellement_ en langue littéraire moderne (LBU14). Aucun ngram ne fait autorité. J'ai modifié ça. Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'*autorité* réfère à l'« [autorité de contrôle](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/FR/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) » ([*supervisory authority*](https://www.cnil.fr/fr/lexique-francais-anglais-sur-la-protection-des-donnees)) signifiant une « une autorité publique indépendante ». Le sens de la locution adjectivale en contexte est plus général au lexique (que celle de la locution nominale) où l'on dit « qui dirige un groupe de pairs » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chef_de_file#Locution_adjectivale)), les pairs étant les autres États membres de l'Union européenne. La *direction* n'est pas basée sur un constat d'excellence ou d'influence mais bien sur une qualification factuelle de nature technique associée au concept de [*compétence*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comp%C3%A9tence) (en droit) :

> [...] une « autorité de contrôle chef de file » est l'autorité qui
>   assume la responsabilité principale de la gestion d'une activité de
>   traitement transfrontalier, par exemple lorsqu’une personne concernée
>   introduit une réclamation concernant le traitement de ses données à
>   caractère personnel.
>
> [ [*Lignes directrices concernant la désignation d'une autorité de
>   contrôle chef de file d'un responsable du traitement ou d’un sous
>   traitant*](https://www.cnil.fr/sites/default/files/atoms/files/wp244rev01_fr.pdf), 16/FR WP 244 rev.01, sur CNIL.fr ]
>
> ---
>
> [...] l'autorité de contrôle de l'établissement principal ou de
>   l'établissement unique du responsable du traitement ou du
>   sous-traitant est compétente pour agir en tant qu'autorité de contrôle
>   chef de file [[version anglaise](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) : *lead supervisory authority*] concernant le traitement transfrontalier effectué par ce
>   responsable du traitement ou ce sous-traitant [...]
>
> [ [*Règlement général sur la protection des données*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8glement_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_sur_la_protection_des_donn%C3%A9es) (RGPD/GDPR),
>   art. [56](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/FR/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) ]
>
> ---
>
> La [CNIL](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_nationale_de_l%27informatique_et_des_libert%C3%A9s_(France)) de l'État où l'entreprise a le « centre de ses activités »
>   dans l'Union européenne est désignée « autorité chef de file »
>
> [ [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chef_de_file#Locution_adjectivale), reprenant les propos de La Quadrature du Net,
>   *Nos plaintes contres les GAFAM avancent !*, 10 octobre 2018 ]

Les guillemets servent à [mettre en valeur](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3391) un terme technique dans un texte qui ne l'est pas et incidemment à créer justement une distance par rapport à l'idée courante qu'on peut se faire du *chef de file* en locution nominale (*market leader*).

Vu qu'à première vue toute *autorité de contrôle chef de file* est une *autorité de contrôle concernée* (art. 4 (22), préambule (36)) mais non inversement, et vu sa responsabilité, il est facile de penser à l'adjectif « principal(e) » comme équivalent usuel de *chef de file* en contexte (*autorité de contrôle principale*).